# Variable not getting executed, Type mismatch error,

Tags: excel, vba, subroutine

- I have filtered data, now I want to select immediate next cell in a row and Define a variable as string of that selected cell.

I tried applying variable as

```
Dim Id as string
Id=wb.ws.range("Q2:Q" & Lr). specialcells(xlcelltypevisible)
```

If I run the variable (Id) it is not executing.

Please help

Comment: You're trying to assign the value of multiple cells (a 2D array) to a String. `ws.range("Q2:Q" & Lr). specialcells(xlcelltypevisible).Cells(1)` maybe?

Comment: If `wb` is a `Workbook` variable, then you can't do `wb.ws`. Just use `ws`.

Comment: Yes, i did the same, like ws=wb.sheets(1)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. Do you want ID to equal the value of a single cell or of many cells? I assume you want ID to equal the value of a single cell and iterate through the visual range of cells. Please clarify.

Comment: Let's say that `ws.Range("Q2:Q" & Lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` refers to the range `ws.Range("Q2,Q5,Q10")`. What do you want to do (with or without `Id`)?

Comment: Data of column Q is in loop, when the loop starts data in column Q gets filtered. Now imagining that in column Q, 3 rows got filtered i.e., Q5, Q8, Q10, now in this scenario of I want to define variable as string for Q5. Now in the same way whenever I go to next loop, variable defined should capture the immediate next cell in the filtered row.

Answer (score 0):

### The First Visible Cell

```vb
Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("Q2:Q" & Lr)

Dim vrg As Range, Id As String

'For...

    On Error Resume Next
        Set vrg = rg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not vrg Is Nothing Then ' there are fltered rows
        Id = CStr(vrg.Cells(1).Value)
        ' Continue...
        
        Set vrg = Nothing ' reset for the next iteration
    'Else ' there are no fltered rows; do nothing!?
    End If

'Next...
```